# Using .Net Web Control - How to Set a Value in a TextBox *INSIDE* of an IFRAME

Tags: .net, browser, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to use a .Net WebBrowser control to log into a website and aggregate some data for me.  I'm also using a reference to MSHTML (but I don't care if your solution does or doesn't).

When I visit a 'normal' website - I create an mshtml.HTMLDocument from the webBrowser's .documment.  Then I create a mshtml.FormElement and a mshtml.HTMLInputElement using the name of the textbox I want.

Then, I can set the value of the textBox.

It looks something like this:

```
    Dim myDoc1 As mshtml.HTMLIFrame = DirectCast(Me.WebBrowser.Document.DomDocument, mshtml.HTMLDocument)
    Dim myForm As mshtml.HTMLFormElement = DirectCast(myDoc1.forms.item(0), mshtml.HTMLFormElement)
    Dim myUserBox As mshtml.HTMLInputElement = DirectCast(myForm.item("user"), mshtml.HTMLFormElement)

    myUserBox.value = UserName
```

My problem is that on some websites the textbox I need to manipulate is contained inside of an IFRAME.  An example would be https://servicing.capitalone.com/c1/login.aspx

If my program surfs to that site - it can't find a textbox for the Username - because there isn't one.  There is only an IFRAME tag that has a URL of 'https://login.capitalone.com/loginweb/login/login.do'

If I surf directly to the login.do page - the website redirects me to an error page.

How can I enter data into the UserName textbox in that IFRAME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the child iframe you are trying to access is coming from a different domain than the parent page, you won't be able to access the form elements of the iframe due to cross-frame scripting security. See: [Accessing Frames in the Managed HTML Document Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171715.aspx)

> Access to frames is complicated by the
>   fact that the managed HTML DOM
>   implements a security measure known as
>   cross-frame scripting security. If a
>   document contains a FRAMESET with two
>   or more FRAMEs in different domains,
>   these FRAMEs cannot interact with one
>   another. In other words, a FRAME that
>   displays content from your Web site
>   cannot access information in a FRAME
>   that hosts a third-party site such as
>   http://www.adatum.com/. This security
>   is implemented at the level of the
>   HtmlWindow class. You can obtain
>   general information about a FRAME
>   hosting another Web site, such as its
>   URL, but you will be unable to access
>   its Document or change the size or
>   location of its hosting FRAME or
>   IFRAME.

Comment: So - there is no way to programatically log into the Capital One Website using a WebBrowser control?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. There is an API for accessing the iframes, but any time I touched the child frame I got a security exception.

Comment: I've hacked together a solution.  I'm using SendKeys to tab a few times until I'm in the right field, then enter a username, tab, password, tab, click the submit button.  

But this is buggy and prone to errors.  If anyone else has a better soltuion I'd be interested to hear it :)